# I want to install Viber and WhatsApp on Android emulator

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, android-emulator, viber-messenger

I want to install Viber and WhatsApp on Android emulator. Kindly help me out.

Comment: Can you try the advice here: http://shahzadimam.wordpress.com/2012/05/15/instal-whatsapp-in-android-emulator/ and see if that works. I've never managed it myself as I 've never been able to verify the account.

Comment: So what is stopping you? Where's the problem? Maybe you [edit] your question and add some more details?

Answer (score 3):

If you got that .apk file downloaded in your system, you can easily install that by the following steps.

- First of all copy the .apk file to the android sdk --> 'platform-tools' directory
- To start the emulator use type the following command on your terminal

  `cd /path_to_android_sdk/platform-tools`    // press enter

  then type the following to start the emulator

  `emulator -avd <emulator_name>`  // press enter

`<emulator_name>` is the name that you have given when you first created that emulator. If you don't know that name, go to eclipse and click window-->Avd and Sdk manager. On that window you can see the AVD name.

After that wait for a couple of minutes so that the emulator starts. After that, unlock the emulator:

- Open another tab in terminal or open another terminal and type the following commands

  `cd /path_to_android_sdk/platform-tools; ls` //press enter

  Now you should see your application name.

  `adb install <name_of_the_apk>` // press enter
  `./adb install <name_of_the_apk>` // for MAC machine

After that you can see a success message.

- Eventually press on the menu launcher button on the emulator where you can see your application installed. Click on the icon to launch that application.

Comment: That's a great explanation of how to install APK files in the Android emulator using ADB, but the OP doesn't have an APK file to install.

Comment: Ok. We can direct him to download apk files from third party sites(both apps are free, nothing illegal)

Comment: @DanHulme also he didn't mention about that.

Answer (score 0):

You can get .apk files to your PC.
Create a simple html page with a link to your .apk

```
<a href='yourfile.apk'>download</a>
```

Use web browser in Emulator to access and download the file and install from SDCard of Emulator.

Comment: This step is completely unnecessary. If you have access to the APK files, you can put them in the emulator's SD card image directly. But that's not useful unless you have the APK file to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Since WhatsApp is installed you have to activate it, but they blocked activation via SMS for  emulator-based installation, so use «Call me» activation option.

They call you and type the given number, that should enable WhatsApp to use on AVD-emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way

1) Download the apk file from http://www.whatsapp.com/android/current/WhatsApp.apk

2) Drag the apk file on Android Emulator and Follow the Steps